# Prefixfree-min.js not working with external css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, external, prefix

Hello I was creating a webpage, and using internal css. I copied the whole css code in an external file and linked it with my html.

Prior to this, prefixfree.js was working fine, but as soon as I copied it to external css the prefixfree.js stopped working with chrome. Firefox is working but chrome doesn't play animations and transitions. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: why my question is vote down -1. its a valid question. i could not found a single answer thats why posted here. whats wrong with this??? If you have link of same question post here in the comment and then vote down -1. .Totally unfair.

Comment: you may not be all that you want to connect or not hooked up correctly

Comment: provide part of the code where you have a bug

Comment: all the animations and transitions are not working in chrome where as firefox aminates it correctly. no-moz- and no-webkit- just prefix-free-min.js

Comment: Please comment here if you have 100% working prefixfree.JS

Comment: if there is not a complex animation, it can be done through css?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62813/discussion-between-alex-wilson-and-waqar-adil-mughal).

Comment: Alex please join chat

Comment: The animation is in CSS already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex wilson. Unprefixed linked stylesheets won’t work locally in Chrome and Opera. Firefox (and IE?) natively support local XHR, so -prefix-free will work fine locally with them.
To enable local XHR for Chrome, you need to run it with the flag --allow-file-access-from-files.
To enable local XHR for Opera, you have to go to opera:config#UserPrefs|AllowFileXMLHttpRequest, check that option and Save.